# Enable pin with maximum 3.0v

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, voltage-divider, input

I've an Enable pin active-high that have maximum voltage rating of 3.0v, but I use a 3.3v MCU outputs. I've also a 3.0v voltage regulator on board.

Should I use resistor voltage divider or there is a possibilty to use 3.0v voltage regulator? And how should I connect it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could just use a simple voltage divider.  However, if you wanted to do it in a more fancy way with the 3.0V supply, you could use a simple resistor and transistor (NPN or N-channel logic level MOSFET) arrangement which inverts the pin so it becomes active low:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVzfMn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So to activate your enable pin you would output a logic LOW, and to disable it a logic HIGH.  It then also becomes the same as most other "Chip Enable" pins which are active low.